# What is a Late Word?

Tags: pattern, word-property, english

(Based off and inspired by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)'s [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) puzzles)

## What Is A Late Word?

Word that conform to a specific rule are called **late** words.
Here are some examples:

| Late Words™ | Non-Late Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| JUPITER | ZEUS |
| MISERY | SUFFERING |
| MYCOSIS | MYCETOZOAN |
| MINERAL | FELDSPAR |
| LIFELIKE | REALISTIC |
| GENERAL | COMMANDER |
| INABILITY | UNABLE |
| PURITY | CLEANLINESS |
| VITAMIN | SUPPLEMENT |

In CSV format:

```
Late Words™,Non-Late Words™
JUPITER,ZEUS
MISERY,SUFFERING
MYCOSIS,MYCETOZOAN
MINERAL,FELDSPAR
LIFELIKFE,REALISTIC
RAVINE,PRECIPICE
GENERAL,COMMANDER
INABILITY,UNABLE
PURITY,CLEANLINESS
VITAMIN,SUPPLEMENT
```

What determines whether a word is or isn't a Late Word™? Why is it called a Late Word™?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Late Word is

> one that alternates consonants and vowels, treating Y as a vowel.

And it's called a Late Word because

> "Late" is another example of a word with this property.